# Silver Searcher: how to unignore files in the .gitignore?

Tags: linux, bash, ack, ag

I have a folder of aliases. These are bash files. Some are sensitive, so I keep them in a `.gitignore`.

```
~/.bash_utilities
   bash_a.sh
   bash_b.sh
   .gitignore
```

.gitignore:
bash_b.sh

The problem is that my Silver Searcher looks at the `.gitignore` and skips those files when looking. How do I tell Silver Searcher to ignore the `.gitignore` file and look in all the files in the directory?

My current command is

```
ag $1 ~/.bash*
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIUC, it's well explained in `man ag`:

> -u --unrestricted
>
> Search all files. This ignores .ignore, .gitignore, etc. It searches binary and hidden files as well.
>
> -U --skip-vcs-ignores
>
> Ignore VCS ignore files (.gitignore, .hgignore), but still use .ignore.